# How to handle a window which automatically closes and says window not found

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have this situation.

Currently on window handling.
I have parent window, child, child1 total 3 windows.
when im selecting some drop down values in parent. It will switch to child (2nd window), in child I have to do basic operation and searching which will take me to child1 (3rd window). After I click submit/double click on data in 3rd window (child1) it will automatically close and come to child (2nd window). After coming to child within 2-3 secs popup/window will open. 
This is where i have to close the popup/window and switch to child (2nd window).
I'm facing issue here, window not found because it is automatically getting closed.

Please help me out. Below is my complete code.

Comment: Can you share website URL?

Comment: Please provide your code and please do not make grammar mistakes

Comment: URL below :  http://dl1cmdbtn11:8080/arsys/shared/login.jsp?/arsys/home

Comment: Find some guidance here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

You could store all the windows in a Set and switch to child window after child1 closes.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.But here what is happening is after click on submit  in 3rd window. 3rd window automatically closes.after that i wrote the code saying switch to 2nd window. but since it is automatically closing it is throwing error window not found in the console.

Comment: If it closes automatically, then try removing the window from the list. Please share the code you are using. Will be able to help with the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The question is little bit confusing.. the main thing here is getting windowHandles into Set.

1. when you do any actions may be click or select which triggers new windows, then go for collecting window handles..

   Set windows=driver.getWindowHandles();

from collected windows you can switch to required window

2. If window is displayed or closed due to any actions, known webdriver does not switch focus automatically.. you need to switch. So due to any action window is closed, switch window which is available as per your requirement.

Please provide clear question, if possible logic developed to help on this

Thanks